# Ошибка при добавлении Flexible в SingleChildScrollView Flutter

Tags: flutter

Мне нужно добавить скролл в меню но при этом есть элементы flexible() и spacer(). И когда добавляю SingleChildScrollView то ошибка. (PS использую styled_widgets)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Эта ошибка ожидаема, т.к. виджет Flexible "безразмерный" - т.е., у него отсутствует явный размер, с которым скролл был бы возможен. По сути об этом текст ошибки и говорит.

Comment: а какое вы поведение хотели бы? И покажите пример с SingleChildScrollView, я объясню, как использовать Spacer() в скроллах, если он будет нужен в вашим кейсе.